# Remove the first line of a twitter bootstrap table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

As you all know when you use Twitter Bootstrap to get a table you get a result like this:
[image]

Would it be possible o remove the very first line of the table, the one above "Abos Girolamo"? Thanks

UPDATE: Here is the code of the table:

```
<table class="table table-no-border">
    <tbody>

      <tr>

        <td>Abos Girolamo</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>Aboulker Isabelle</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>Adam Adolphe</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Specifically, what technology you want to use to cause this effect. In css you can use `first-child`

Comment: I would like to do it in css

Comment: can you give us the source code of this table?

Comment: I updated with the code

Comment: you said you wanted to remove the <hr /> line but it isn't in the source code.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
.table > tbody > tr:first-child > td {
    border: none;
}
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

table {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.table > thead > tr:first-child > td, 
.table > tbody > tr:first-child > td {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-no-border">
    <tbody>

      <tr>

        <td>Abos Girolamo</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>Aboulker Isabelle</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>Adam Adolphe</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: For future visotr, don't forget remove border for first **th**, `.table > tbody > tr:first-child > th {
    border: none;
}` if need

Answer (score 7):

For those who found this question via Google...

Bootstrap tables assume you will use a `thead` in your markup, which is why that top line is present. If you have a mix of tables that include a header and don't include a header, you can use the following CSS to style them correctly.

```
/* Remove the top border when a table is missing the header */
.table > tbody > tr:first-child > td {
    border: none;
}

/* Include the border when there's a header */
.table > thead + tbody > tr:first-child > td {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/colinjmiller93/fwsmpu5u/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery:

```
$('#TableID tr:first-child').remove();

<html><body><table id='TableID'>
<tr>Abos Girolamo</tr>
<tr>Aboulker Isabelle</tr>
<tr>Adam Adolphe</tr>
</table></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS you would need something like:

```
.table > tbody > tr:first-child {
   display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ahallicks/bwbXA/

Comment: Added before your markup, it needed the extra selector for tbody. Changed and fiddle added

Comment: I don't want to remove the first row, but the line, the graphical line above the first raw...

Comment: if it's the first child in the table, that will still work. is the line a <hr /> tag?

Comment: Hah... fail. I thought you meant the whole table row! Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add another possibility that can be useful if you want to do this only for a specific table and don't want any risk that an additional CSS rule could affect existing tables:

Add `style="border-top: none"` to each `<td>` element of the first table row.

E.g.

```html
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-top: none">Abos Girolamo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Aboulker Isabelle</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Adam Adolphe</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some how other answers didn't work for me, below style worked for me -

```
.table {
  border-top-style: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want this:**
[image]

**Here is the code:**

```
table thead {
  background-color: var green !important;
}
table tr {
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid grey;
}
table thead tr:first-of-type {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
table tr th {
  border: 0;
}
table tr td {
  border: 0;
}
```